# use a dynamic key from handlebars template to load i18next key

Tags: handlebars.js, i18next

I'm trying to lookup a key by a variable in i18next using handlebars:

Normally I would do `{{ t "key.name" }}` but for me, `name` is a property of an object, where its value could be anything. I tried doing `{{ t "key[name]" }}` but that didn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

app.json:

```
foo: {
  "one": "One",
  "two" : "Two"
}
```

In handlebars, `{{name}}` would produce `one or two`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I modified the helper a bit so that I can pass two params:

```
{{ t "key" name }}
```

Then inside the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('t', function(key, name) {
  var key = key+"."+name;
  //replace this with reference to i18n, I just created a wrapper around it called Translation
  var result = Translation.get(key); 
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```